# How to print out original padded hash from signature using openssl

Tags: openssl

I want to learn about different padding and identifier or format when signing a file. So i want to know what happens when using openssl

For example:
`openssl dgst -sha256 -sign xiaomi_rootca.key -sigopt rsa_padding_mode:pss -sigopt rsa_pss_saltlen:-1 -out sig.bin 1.txt`

Surely it will generate a `sig.bin`. However i want to know what openssl did to `hash.bin` before it is converted to `sig.bin`

So let's split this process into steps:

1. `openssl dgst -binary -sha256 -out hash.bin 1.txt`
2. padding it
3. maybe add some identifier like rfc3447.txt page 12 says? and generate a final file `final_hash.bin`
4. raw sign. `openssl rsautl -sign -inkey private.key -in fianl_hash.bin -out sig.bin`

Well, i want to know what happened exactly during step 2 and 3. So is there any command to reverse step 4?

Before i can use `openssl rsautl -verify`, however it doesn't support pss pading.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can split it up like you have.

When you are doing a digest only command you use the [EVP_DigestInit](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DigestInit.html) API.  When you use the -sign option it uses the [EVP_DigestSignInit](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DigestSignInit.html) API.

So I *think* it's a little bit more involved than what you have broken down.  To really tell the difference now, you would have to start to look into the engine code, specifically the private key type implementation (e.g. RSA, EC, etc).

Looking at the RSA PSS engine implementation, it looks like the padding is implemented in-line with the signing operation itself.

e.g. in the pkey_rsa_sign function you see code like:

```
} else if (rctx->pad_mode == RSA_PKCS1_PSS_PADDING) {
    if (!setup_tbuf(rctx, ctx))
        return -1;
    if (!RSA_padding_add_PKCS1_PSS_mgf1(rsa,
                                        rctx->tbuf, tbs,
                                        rctx->md, rctx->mgf1md,
                                        rctx->saltlen))
        return -1;
```

If you want to verify a digest it seems like you really want to use the [EVP_DigestVerifyInit](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/EVP_DigestVerifyUpdate.html) API (as this is what the dgst command is using) as I'm not sure you are going to get anywhere going down the path you want to go down in your question.